# Wrong labels when plotting a time series pandas dataframe with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am working with a dataframe containing data of 1 week.

```
                          y
ds                             
2017-08-31 10:15:00    1.000000
2017-08-31 10:20:00    1.049107
2017-08-31 10:25:00    1.098214
...
2017-09-07 10:05:00   99.901786
2017-09-07 10:10:00   99.950893
2017-09-07 10:15:00  100.000000
```

I create a new index by combining the weekday and time i.e.

```
                y
dayIndex             
4 - 10:15    1.000000
4 - 10:20    1.049107
4 - 10:25    1.098214
...
4 - 10:05   99.901786
4 - 10:10   99.950893
4 - 10:15  100.000000
```

The plot of this data is the following:
[image: Weekly data]
The plot is correct as the labels reflect the data in the dataframe. However, when zooming in, the labels do not seem correct as they no longer correspond to their original values:
[image: Wrong labels when zooming]
What is causing this behavior?

Here is the code to reproduce this:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dtnow = datetime.datetime.now()
dindex = pd.date_range(dtnow , dtnow  + datetime.timedelta(7), freq='5T')
data = np.linspace(1,100, num=len(dindex))
df = pd.DataFrame({'ds': dindex, 'y': data})
df = df.set_index('ds')
df = df.resample('5T').mean()
df['dayIndex'] = df.index.strftime('%w - %H:%M')
df= df.set_index('dayIndex')
df.plot()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"What is causing this behavior?"*

The formatter of an axes of a pandas dates plot is a `matplotlib.ticker.FixedFormatter` (see e.g.
`print plt.gca().xaxis.get_major_formatter()`). "Fixed" means that it formats the `i`th tick (if shown) with some constant string.

When zooming or panning, you shift the tick locations, but not the format strings.
In short: A pandas date plot may not be the best choice for interactive plots.

**Solution**

A solution is usually to use matplotlib formatters directly. This requires the dates to be `datetime` objects (which can be ensured using `df.index.to_pydatetime()`).

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates

dtnow = datetime.datetime.now()
dindex = pd.date_range(dtnow , dtnow  + datetime.timedelta(7), freq='110T')
data = np.linspace(1,100, num=len(dindex))
df = pd.DataFrame({'ds': dindex, 'y': data})
df = df.set_index('ds')
df.index.to_pydatetime()
df.plot(marker="o")


plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%w - %H:%M'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How come the format strings do not shift along with the ticks? Do you know if this is by design, or should this reported as issue? I am referring to my original code. The one you posted works great.

Comment: The fact that a `FixedFormatter` fixes the labels such that they are bound to the index of the label is by design (hence the name). Whether or not the fact that pandas datetime plots *use* a FixedFormatter would be seen as an issue, is probably a matter of taste. It has several advantages, but you ran into a case where it is undesired. I thus wouldn't call it a bug or so, but you may sure report it as a *feature request* if you like.