# Wrong year of datetime in Matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I observed that the year data, which is the horizontal axis in my Matplotlib graph was wrong. All my data was from the year of 2020, but the graph displayed 1970-1980.

df:

```
    Timestamp               Value
36  2020-11-08 23:30:40.370 45.5
47  2020-11-13 04:52:29.410 44.5
67  2020-12-01 22:17:50.300 42.5
129 2020-11-24 00:57:11.950 43.0
176 2020-12-03 01:40:16.250 42.0
246 2020-11-12 07:32:54.000 43.5
281 2020-11-30 21:13:07.630 45.5
335 2020-11-30 20:43:11.050 43.5
    ...
```

Graph looks like this:

[image]

According to [@ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45982707/11901732), I figured the issue might be with the format of pandas dates. So I tried:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df.set_index('Timestamp')
df.index.to_pydatetime()
```

This returned:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-394-d7c25df8c8d8> in <module>
     38 df.set_index('Timestamp')
     39 
---> 40 df.index.to_pydatetime()
     41 

AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'to_pydatetime'
```

What is the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing

```
df.set_index('Timestamp',inplace=True)
```

If you want to avoid `inplace=True`, you can also do

```
import datetime as dt     
df['Timestamp'].dt.to_pydatetime()
```

This should give you a numpy array of python datetime objects.